# How to assign a custom symbol to a UIButton using Unicode?

Tags: ios, button, unicode, xcode6

I want to assign some Unicode symbols to UIButtons. I have tried different approaches but couldn't find one that worked. This screenshot shows what I want to achieve:

[image]

So far I've tried:

```
 [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\u27F2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\U27F2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\U+27F2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"U+27F2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

In all cases my button shows question mark with box.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Actually if you are statically assigning the symbol then it is available in XCode:  Edit>Special Characters> Arrows.   The same symbol is available in Miscellaneous Arrows Section there. Hope this helped.

Comment: Actually i am using custom symbols which is not available there. i have hundreds of other custom symbols which i will use later in my app.so looking for way how to use custom symbols?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `"\u{27F2}"`, or in obj-c: `@"\u27F2"`, to get a Unicode string. If it doesn´t show up or shows a question mark, then the font you are using doesn´t support that glyph. Then find a Font family that has that glyph (letter).

**Swift 3.0**

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 66, height: 66))
button.setTitle("\u{27F2}", for: [])
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"AvenirNext-UltraLight", size: 46)
```

**Objective-C:**

```
[button setTitle:@"\u27F2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-UltraLight" size:21.0];
```

Comment: i have tried with your provided font but no luck.AvenirNext-UltraLigh have this icon?

Comment: @Shazad - sorry but AvenirNext does not have this icon. I did´t have time to check all fonts. But if you got the code to work then that is your last step: find the relevant font.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\u` in a string to specify the unicode identifier. For exmaple:

```
[button setTitle:@"\u27F2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score -1):

i hope that you have already, but first make sure that you have select button type as custom for uibutton and then try any one of these:

1. use option + key combination for IB
2. **REPLACE [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\u27F2"]       forState:UIControlStateNormal];**
   *WITH THIS ONE*
   [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:@"\u27F2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
3. use font that support unicode like **'Symbola'**

Comment: `stringWithUTF8String:@"\u27F2"` makes no sense and would not compile.